# JavaScript onclick .closest gives error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to update the box-content (closest div with class of box-content) to the returned data from an ajax call but I receive an error.

the .box-content is a class of 5 divs on the page but shouldn't the closest be able to find the closest one? Each box has a box-content class and its the parent of the parent if that makes sense?

Html:

```
<div style="margin-top:12%;" id="removeButton" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="fireGovernmentMember({{ $playerRp->user_id }}, this);"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;Remove</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function fireGovernmentMember(playerId, element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + 'api/ajax/owner/fire_gov',
        type: "GET",
        data: { 
            player_id: playerId,
        },
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification("Something went wrong", response.responseText, 3000);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification("Something went wrong", response.responseText, 3000);
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            element.closest('.box-content').html(data);
            showSuccessNotification("Action Completed", "Item has been removed from user.", 1000);
        },
    });
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null
    at Object.success (override.js?v=1502133651:806)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
```

Comment: And where is `element` coming from? Something tells me it's a native DOM node, and not a jQuery element

Comment: You are passing 'this' in on the inline onclick.  It will not be a jquery object.  Wrap it in $() to make it an object for access to closest()

Comment: because element ain't jQuery

Answer (score 2):

`element` in your code is a native DOM node, as you're passing just `this` to the function.

That means you're using the native `closest()` and not jQuery's version of it, which is why it returns `null` and not an empty collection.

You have to do

```
$(element).closest('.box-content').html(data);
```

But seeing as the native method fails, jQuery's version probably will as well, but at least it will fail silently.

Make sure there really is parent element with the class `box-content` to make the `closest()` method actually find an element.

One does wonder why you wouldn't use proper event handlers instead, something like

```
<div id="removeButton" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-id="{{ $playerRp->user_id }}">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;Remove
</div>
```

and then

```
$('#removeButton').on('click', function() {
    var playerId = $(this).data('id');
    var self     = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + 'api/ajax/owner/fire_gov',
        type: "GET",
        data: { player_id: playerId },
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification("Something went wrong", response.responseText, 3000);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification("Something went wrong", response.responseText, 3000);
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            self.closest('.box-content').html(data);
            showSuccessNotification("Action Completed", "Item has been removed from user.", 1000);
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, my .box-content isn't found, is there a reason for this? It's a parent of a parent.

Comment: I can't really tell what the problem is, as I haven't seen your HTML, nor the rest of the code. Generally if the element is a parent somewhere up the chain from `element` it should find it.